# how to change what shift(toggle ) key does permanently?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

upgraded my ubuntu 18.04 by running

```
sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

it asked me about toggling between languages And I accindently chose left shift as result when I press my left shift it just changes the language and I can't use it for caps which is annoying! 
I tried :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
service keyboard-setup restart
```

but the changes don't save and after a few minute the left shift still unavailable! 
I tried to change it by going to setting > language & region but it doesn't show the shift key as toggling key :

[image]

then I tried to chane it via

```
sudo nano etc/default keyboard
```

the left shift still not working! how can I change it to be normal permanently?

[image]

Comment: Hi, what is the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: first install gnome-tweaks with this command `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` and then check what options are ticked for switch input layouts section like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/JecvK.png

Comment: hi, the output is ;  GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
@as []

Comment: this is unusual output.. are you using wayland?? have you checked gnome tweaks??

Comment: thank u I was able to correct it with tweaks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the same mistake during installation of 20.10. A quick search led me to
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
which would fix the problem but the problem would reappear after a reboot. This morning I finally got around to look further into the issue. Trying all the gnome-tweaks or dconf didn't work for me. What I found was that in
/etc/default/keyboard I had:
XKBOPTIONS="grp:lshift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
Deleting the lshift-part did it for me.